# css input required not focused or disabled

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a css rule to change the background color of an input if it is required, but bot disabled or in focus

I have this, but it's not working obviously!

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" value="" required>
```

and css:

```
input:not(disabled):not(focus):required {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.10)
}
```

Comment: What you have is working just fine for me, https://jsfiddle.net/bomnrm0d/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `:` for your pseudo-selectors `:disabled` and `:focus`

```
input:required:not(:disabled):not(:focus)
```

Comment: yep that was the ticket!

Comment: @Roko please add some explanation..  is it the order?

Comment: @tech  sorry i'm mobile and was searching for the ` character :) no. the order is not important but the missing `:`